# Как вызвать метод из репозитория?

Tags: php, symfony2

```
   ->add('healthPlan', EntityType::class, [
                'class'         => Organization::class,
                'choice_label'  => function ($value, $key) {
                    return 1;
                },
                'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                    return $er->findAll();
               }
            ])
```

Пишет что хочет query  а там, как бы, массив, но мне в принципе нужен OrganizationRepository

Только не предлагайте писать запрос через query_builder так как нужен вызов именно функции

Comment: во первый предоставьте код вашего ```OrganizationRepository```

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь опцией [`choices`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#choices)
например

```
->add(
    'healthPlan', 
    EntityType::class, 
    [
        'class' => Organization::class,
        'choice_label'  => function ($value, $key) {
            return 1;
        },
        'choices' => function () use ($organizationRepository) {
            return $organizationRepository->customMethod();
        }
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Хочу поделиться своим подходом.

В своей практике часто сталкиваюсь с ситуацией, когда требуется либо QueryBuilder по-определенному построенный, либо уже его результат. На мой взгляд, удобнее иметь 2 метода в репозитории:

getBySomeCriteriaQueryBuilder() - вернет QueryBuilder

getBySomeCriteria() - вернет уже результат выборки, например:

```
public function getBySomeCriteria() {
    return $this->getBySomeCriteriaQueryBuilder()->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Конкретно в вашем случае, удобство в том, что не нужно ничего лишнего прокидывать в класс формы. У вас в анонимную функцию уже [передается](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder) репозиторий - только вызов метода нужно вставить:

```
   ->add('healthPlan', EntityType::class, [
            'class'         => Organization::class,
            'choice_label'  => function ($value, $key) {
                return 1;
            },
            'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->getBySomeCriteriaQueryBuilder();
           }
        ])
```

Также, в дальнейшем, на основании этого QueryBuilder можно будет строить иные, более сложные условия, что избавит от дублирования кода.